# powering 900 led's

Tags: led, power, portable

I am hoping to make an LED panel for video recording.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLia59KfkSw) 
is the video I am building based on. I am relatively a novice when it comes to electrical work, but I am competent. This project will use 900 LED's. The LED's in question can be found 
[here.](http://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B00HSF65MC) In the video, the guy makes a battery pack using a lithium-ion polymer battery pack from an rc car. This seems kind of expensive.

If I were to buy 3 packs of those LED's (900 individual), what would I be looking at for a power supply that would be portable? I was hoping for some sort of power bank?

Comment: I watched a minute of that video. I'm not sure when a kilowatt became a measurement of light output.

Comment: You should research and outline how much power you need and at what voltage. This will narrow down your options.

Comment: Buying power supplies for higher power levels is always expensive for the most part. You need to decide how you're configuring the LEDs (series/parallel sets) in order to determine the required voltage and current to drive the LEDs. 

RC batteries are actually a pretty good way to go. They're not super expensive and can supply a pretty decent amount of current. Chargers for them are also relatively inexpensive.

Comment: Also, don't overlook the need for heat sinks -- automotive LED assemblies are normally built on a large block of aluminum, to dissipate the excess heat (Vf x If) and avoid shortening the product lifetime. For a small LED project this is often overlooked, but at 900 LEDs (and a kiloWatt of power?) this could be a significant factor.

Comment: The LED is specified as a "3528" type, which turns up a plethora of datasheets such as [this one](http://www.lumimicro.com/eng/20_product/pdf/LMTPWH10A2Z.pdf) and [this](http://www.wayjun.com/Datasheet/Led/3528%20SMD%20LED.pdf). Without a valid datasheet, it is impossible to determine your maximum current and thus, maximum brightness. But both of these show around 40mA (0.040A) per LED, which sounds reasonable to me, and would produce the kind of brightness shown in the video. 40mA x 900 pcs = 36A.

Comment: @rdtsc, but 36 A * 3 V = 108W. So that is far from 1 kW.

Comment: OK. I watched the video. So he said it was around 100 W of electrical power. I guess that is plausible.

Answer (score 1):

On the product info page ([not Amazon's, manufacturer's](http://www.lightingever.com/12v-led-strip-light-3528-4100057-dw.html)), it says that each lamp takes up 2 mA, and with 3 strips of 300, that's 1.8A. All you would need is a 2A 12VDC adapter/battery.

The power supply that is advertized with the LEDs is 3A, just to ensure there is enough power probably.

Anything above 2A 12VDC should be fine.

The power supply that the guy in the video used was significantly higher, probably because his LEDs needed more current. The kilowatts of power he was talking about was simply comparing to standard incandescents.

No heat sink should be necessary because 2A is not going to create much heat, and anyway, "It is touchable and safe to children." :)

But, remember that more amps is fine. **Never power anything with too many volts.** If you aren't sure, up the amps.

Good luck!